# Get Data From JSON Decode PHP Array Assoc

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

Need help here Please.

I have this type array from `json_decode($items)`. The output array is like below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [recipient_type] => EMAIL
            [note] => For Sender
            [receiver] => abc@gmail.com
            [sender_item_id] => BB_000001
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [recipient_type] => EMAIL
            [note] => For Sender
            [receiver] => cde@gmail.com
            [sender_item_id] => BB_000002
        )

)
```

Then I used this code to get the data from the array :

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    $data = array(
                'RecipientType' => $item->RecipientType,  
                'Note'          => $item->Note,  
                'Receiver'      => $item->Receiver,
    );
}
```

But i got error on $item->RecipeientType said :

> Trying to get property of non-object

Seem that I cannot get The data from the array.

How should I get the data in the right way?

Thank You

Comment: `$item` is a non-object variable, you have to access the value using index e.g:`$item['recipient_type'], $item['note'], etc.`

Comment: You say you've used `json_decode($items)` but the output array in your question says you used `json_decode($items, true)`. Next time, please provide **all** the relevant code

Comment: @catcon thank you. this is exactly what i mean. But with json_decode set to true.

Comment: @Phil yes thank you, when i set json decode to true i can get the item with $item['recipient_type']

Comment: You are not getting an array of objects. So do like this. 

`$data = array(
                'RecipientType' => $item['RecipientType'],  
                'Note'          => $item['Note'],  
                'Receiver'      => $item['Receiver'],
    );`

Comment: @DanishAli Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original array has the key `recipient_type` so it should be `$item->recipient_type` as well.

Besides, `json_decode` has a second boolean parameter that gives you an array right away. Try  `json_decode($items, true)`

Comment: almost get it right, but with json_decode set to true i cannot get the array item using $item->recipeitn_type, it must use $item['recipient_type']. But LOL i type a wrong key haha. thank you for showing the mistake.